# php else statement for empty search

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, search, keyword

I have a search function which matches keywords from a database and echo's out some html but I'm missing how to enable the handling of empty searches. Can I use an else statement or do I have to redefine the same parameters and use !isset for if not set?

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "database", "password", "table");
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $search_query = $_GET['search_query'];

    global $con;
    $get_item = "select * from database where keywords like '%$search_query%'";
    $run_item = mysqli_query($con, $get_item);
    while ($row_item = mysqli_fetch_array($run_item)) {

        $item_keywords = $row_item['item_keywords'];

        echo "Search found for $search_query";
    } // working fine up to here
} else {
    echo "Search not found for $search_query";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isset()` and `mysqli_num_rows()` to check empty result. ANd use `mysqli_real_escape_string` for fire your query

```
 if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['search_query']) && $_GET['search_query'] != "") {/// check variable is set or not
        $search_query = $_GET['search_query'];
        $$search_query = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $search_query);//
        $get_item = "select * from `database` where `keywords` like '%$search_query%'";
        $run_item = mysqli_query($con, $get_item);
        $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($run_item); // count number of rows
        if ($row_cnt > 0) {
            while ($row_item = mysqli_fetch_array($run_item)) {
                $item_keywords = $row_item['item_keywords'];
                echo "Search found for $item_keywords";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Search not found for $item_keywords";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Search not found for $item_keywords";
    }
}
```

Comment: Best answer on this question. I'd add a note about SQL injections.

Comment: thanks @chris85 i have added `mysqli_real_escape_string` for preventing SQL injections

Answer (score 1):

You can set condition for empty search like this.

```
if (isset($_GET['search']) && trim($_GET['search']) !='') { ... }
```

Comment: @Steven you can always accept this answer by clicking on the tick mark under the voting part!

Comment: Why not just use `empty`? How does this tell if there are records or not?

Comment: @chris85 If somebody submit a space then empty condition not working. So we have to trim that search variable and then we can set it in to empty condition.

Answer (score 1):

Change your condition to:

```
if (isset($_GET['search']) && trim($_GET['search_query']) != '') { 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your if condition

```
if (isset($_GET['search']) && !empty($_GET['search_query'])) { 

}
```

Comment: This doesn't tell if there are records. Should use the `!empty` on the `search` GET as well, currently allowing that to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the `empty` function:

```
if (!empty($_GET['search'])) {
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Why `isset`? This doesn't tell if there are records or not.